# Placeholder not working in IE10

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

html:

```
<div class="div-input">
    <input type="text" id="loginname" name="username" value="" maxlength="25" 
        class="form-input" placeholder="Username"
    />
</div>
<div class="div-input">
    <input type="password" id="loginpassword" name="password" maxlength="25" 
        class="form-input" placeholder="Password"
    />
</div>
<div>
    <input type="submit" name="login" value="LOGIN" class="form-button" 
        onclick="return check_login(&quot;/&quot;)" 
    />
    <span id="logInfo"></span><span style="display: none;" id="overlay"></span>
    <span style="display: none;" id="popup">
        <img src="/public/images/loading.gif" />
    </span>
</div>
```

My problem is that the placeholder is working fine in all browsers, for IE8 and IE9 I used Javascript to solve it, but in IE10 the placeholder is working, but not in a correct manner.

1. What happens is that on page load, if `Placeholder` is the placeholder, I get only `Placeholde` as placeholder in IE10 (last letter disappears), but if I click in the input box and outside the page it shows the correct placeholder as `Placeholder`.
2. If I type any word in the input field I am getting a cross symbol (close symbol) at the corner in the input field which is happening only in IE10.

Comment: **2nd point** is the feature of IE-10 for deleting all the content from the textbox

Comment: The problem is not in the markup. You probably have some script that breaks placeholder in IE 10. You should add it to the question.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

i am not sure about placeHolder attribute  for input support in ie10,but if u want a placeholder in ie u can do this throug jquery like this below..

```
if(navigator.appVersion.match(/MSIE [\d.]+/)){
    var placeholderText = 'Some Placeholder Text';
    $('#loginname').val(placeholderText);
    $('#loginname').blur(function(){
        $(this).val() == '' ? $(this).val(placeholderText) : false;
    });
    $('#loginname').focus(function(){
        $(this).val() == placeholderText ? $(this).val('') : false;
    });
}
```

u can do same for password too..

Have U tried somewhat like this using code...i believe should work...

```
$('#loginname').attr('placeholder', 'username');
$('#password').attr('placeholder', 'password');
```

Comment: k just call this two lines in function and call the function after page is loaded..should work..

Comment: I checked your 1st solution(because of less code) for ie 8 & ie 9 it does not work for me,do i need to add any script apart from this.

Comment: both solutions i have added is the coding way of controlling the placeholder for the input fields placing this in script part should work..any help still needed u can revert back...

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your javascript is breaking the native IE10 placeholder functionality.

To test this, and hopefully fix it, wrap the javascript you have written for placeholders in a conditional statement, so that it only applies to IE9 and below.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script>
  document.createElement('header');
  document.createElement('nav');
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Alternatively, there is a very nice jquery plugin by Mathias Bynens that is available for free and handles all of this for you:  https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder

Some CMSs already have a plugin built using this code.  The Wordpress plugin is here: http://wordpress.org/plugins/html5-placeholder-polyfill/

Comment: Thanks flr the Mathias Bynens plugin, it works great when loaded with conditional IE comments. Wrap the js and `.placeholder()` code in `<!--[if lte IE 10]>`

Answer (score -2):

Try this, is jquery pluin for placeholder in browser that don't support perfectly it. Leaving your php code and adding this js it should work:

```
(function($) {

/**
 * Spoofs placeholders in browsers that don't support them (eg Firefox 3)
 * 
 * Copyright 2011 Dan Bentley
 * Licensed under the Apache License 2.0
 *
 * Author: Dan Bentley [github.com/danbentley]
 */

// Return if native support is available.
if ("placeholder" in document.createElement("input")) return;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(':input[placeholder]').not(':password').each(function() {
        setupPlaceholder($(this));
    });

    $(':password[placeholder]').each(function() {
        setupPasswords($(this));
    });

    $('form').submit(function(e) {
        clearPlaceholdersBeforeSubmit($(this));
    });
});

function setupPlaceholder(input) {

    var placeholderText = input.attr('placeholder');

    setPlaceholderOrFlagChanged(input, placeholderText);
    input.focus(function(e) {
        if (input.data('changed') === true) return;
        if (input.val() === placeholderText) input.val('');
    }).blur(function(e) {
        if (input.val() === '') input.val(placeholderText); 
    }).change(function(e) {
        input.data('changed', input.val() !== '');
    });
}

function setPlaceholderOrFlagChanged(input, text) {
    (input.val() === '') ? input.val(text) : input.data('changed', true);
}

function setupPasswords(input) {
    var passwordPlaceholder = createPasswordPlaceholder(input);
    input.after(passwordPlaceholder);

    (input.val() === '') ? input.hide() : passwordPlaceholder.hide();

    $(input).blur(function(e) {
        if (input.val() !== '') return;
        input.hide();
        passwordPlaceholder.show();
    });

    $(passwordPlaceholder).focus(function(e) {
        input.show().focus();
        passwordPlaceholder.hide();
    });
}

function createPasswordPlaceholder(input) {
    return $('<input>').attr({
        placeholder: input.attr('placeholder'),
        value: input.attr('placeholder'),
        id: input.attr('id'),
        readonly: true
    }).addClass(input.attr('class'));
}

function clearPlaceholdersBeforeSubmit(form) {
    form.find(':input[placeholder]').each(function() {
        if ($(this).data('changed') === true) return;
        if ($(this).val() === $(this).attr('placeholder')) $(this).val('');
    });
}
})(jQuery);
```

Then you have to invoke the plugin in your php page or in another js simply by:

```
 $(function() {
    // Invoke the plugin
    $('input, textarea').placeholder();       
   });
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Would be nice to comment when you downvote so that others can understand the downvotes. Otherwise, I have no idea what might be wrong with this comment.