# button and input with border red only in mozilla firefox

Tags: html, css, mozilla

I developed a search form with css and jQuery for when i click in my submit button the input box expands.
In google chrome everything is work fine..

But in mozilla firefox When I click in the button to expand, the input expands with a border right and then when the input contracts the button stays with the red border in the left.

I´m trying to solve this with outline none in my #test but its not working...

Anyone there know How I can solve this in mozilla?

**My html:**

```
<li id="sb-search" style="float:right; list-style:none; height:20px;">
          <div id="search-container">
              <span id="search" class="form-container cf">
                 <form  name="form1" >
                       <input id="test" type="search" placeholder="Search..." required="required"  onblur="if(this.placeholder == ''){this.placeholder ='Search...'}" />
                       <button class="expand"  type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                 </form>
             </span> 
          </div>
    </li>
```

**My css:**

```
#test
{
       font-family:'bariolthin';
       font-size:17px;
       line-height:18px;
       outline:none;
       border:0;
}

.form-container input 
{
        width: 150px;
        height: 30px;
        float: left;    
        font: bold 15px;
        font-size:15px;
        font-family:'bariol_lightlight';
        border: 0;
        background: #f3f3f3; 
        border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;  
        color:#000;  
        margin-top:8px;
        display:none;
        outline:none;
}

.form-container button 
{
        overflow: visible;
        position: relative;
        float: right;
        border: 0;
        padding: 0;
        cursor: pointer;
        height: 30px;
        width: 35px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        background: #141d22;
        border: 3px solid #141d22;
        border-radius: 5px;      
        text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0 ,0, .3);
        margin-top:8px;
        outline:none;
        border:none;
    }
```

**My jQuery:**

```
$(function() {
    $('button.expand').click(function(event) {
        $('#test').width(0).addClass('visible').show().animate({width: 180}, 500);
        event.stopPropagation();
});
    $('#test').click(function(event) {
        $('#test').width(180);
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
    $('html').click(function() {
        if($('#test').hasClass("visible")){
            $('#test').width(180).show().animate({width: 0}, 500).removeClass("visible");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: try to use "important" like this:
outline:0 !important;
border:0 !important;

Comment: Thank you Moussawi7...but even with that the problem continues!

Comment: Can I see the code Online?!

Comment: yes..i create a jsfiddle with the code: http://jsfiddle.net/ue7FM/1/

Comment: Obviously, it is required that a problem, it must be Firefox that runs like this

Comment: Man, It's Box-shadow,,
#test
{/*Old properties*/
  box-shadow:none
}

Comment: Thank you...I didn´t imagine that it could be for that! Thank you very much! Can you give the answer so I can accept?

Comment: And maybe you can help me with other bug, now internet explorer, What a strange situation. In internext explorer my placeholder = "Search..." dont appears. Just appears when the input is contracting but when the input expands the placeholder dont appaers :S

Comment: @CesarM, What version of Internet explorer you are using?!

Comment: I´m using IE Version 10!

Comment: I´m not see what might be wrong, do you think its a css or jQuery problem?

Comment: In fact I have no internet explorer 10 installed on my laptop, but this answer may help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19312069/placeholder-not-working-in-ie10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reset box-shadow.

```
 #test {
   font-family:'bariolthin';
   font-size:17px;
   line-height:18px;
   outline:none;
   border:0;
   box-shadow:none;
 }
```