# Textarea placeholder not disappearing on focus/typing in IE10

Tags: javascript, jquery, placeholder

net mvc web application in which I have multiple `textarea` and `input` fields. Now the placeholder is working great in all browsers (chrome, firefox) but in `Internet Explorer 10`, the placeholder text doesn't disappear on focus or on typing in the text area.

```
<textarea placeholder="Write Query..." maxlength="1000"></textarea>
```

A colleague of mine told me that this is due to a bug in jquery having version < 1.8.3 ? is this true? is there any workaround for it ? I am just adding some pages to existing application so I am not allowed to change/update the jquery library.

P.S I am using Jquery 1.11.1 (I know its way old)

Comment: Please show us the code, or create a fiddle

Comment: The placeholder attribute is valid in HTML5, and is supported by IE10: http://caniuse.com/#search=placeholder. The fact you're using jQuery 1.8.3 has no bearing on this at all. Please post your JS code related to that textarea.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Unless jQuery 1.8.3 isn't aware of IE10's support for `placeholder` and therefore tries to override the native behaviour... Long shot, but possible.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/w7dYr/

Comment: Same thing happened here, I guess my colleague was right. It is a bug. However I would appreciate some workaround. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189538/comment-hint-not-disappearing-when-i-start-to-type-comment

Comment: Havent tested the code but the accepted answer here seems to be a workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19312069/placeholder-not-working-in-ie10

Comment: Your demo fiddle has the ` $('.placeholder')` selector, but that `<textarea>` does not have that class on it.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowedge, this is an IE issue and has nothing to do with jQuery. 
I've worked around it manually by adding a focus listener to the textarea.

```
<textarea onfocus="removePlaceholderText" placeholder="Write Query..." maxlength="1000"></textarea>
```

which does the following:

```
function removePlaceholderText(event) {
    var element = event.currentTarget;
    var value = element.value;
    var placeholder = element.getAttribute('placeholder');
    if (placeholder === value) {
        element.value = '';
    }
}
```

Comment: Some people say you shouldn't use placeholders at all: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/06/placeholder-attribute/